# Django admin prepopulate field not error "d.Keyup is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

When I moved my new site from development to my production server, which is using passenger wsgi, the prepopulate admin fields stopped working.  Using firebug I get the error "d.Keyup is not a function" in the prepopulate.min.js file.  All the admin js files seem to be getting incorporated correctly so I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Any ideas?

--Update--

Problem solved see below.

Comment: You maybe have some code to help you better out?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept that answer, that lets people know the question has been answered correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay managed to solve it myself, feel quite silly now too.

When I started development I used django 1.2.3 and when I went to production I just pip installed django which installed version 1.2.4. However I had to move the admin media into my public folder to server it using passenger and I used the 1.2.3 admin media from my development machine with django version 1.2.4 on the server and this apparently caused the problem.

Basically make sure you use the correct admin media for the version of django you are using :P